# Cannot post request to localdomain 127.0.0.1:80 in RHEL7

Tags: linux, putty, redhat-enterprise-linux

When I try to post request to 127.0.0.1, it shows error as:

```
Post http://localhost/users: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

I have tried following:

Wget:

```
wget 127.0.0.1
--2020-04-02 09:52:01--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

Traceroute:

```
traceroute 127.0.0.1
traceroute to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.062 ms  0.029 ms  0.027 ms
```

Ping:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
87 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 86006ms
```

Can anyone help with configuring this.

Comment: You're trying to connect to a port but are you sure something is listening on that port? Check if `ss -l` shows port 80

Comment: Did you install some HTTP server? The server config file would be the first thing to add to your question.

Comment: @HoD No nothing is displayed there for port 80.

Comment: @xenoid Actually I am trying to setup Mainflux, they have their internal code so I can't see their server config file.

Comment: You may need to ask a new question "I'm setting up MainFlux and there is nothing listening to port 80", possibly on the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/) site.  But the first thing would be to check that MainFlux is actually running.

Comment: @xenoid Yes correct. I am going to do that. No how to close this issue here?

Comment: You can delete your question...

Comment: @xenoid I have deleted a lot of questions, now it says if I delete more it will block me from asking the questions.

Comment: Then leave it around but you shouldn't be deleting questions in the general case. You should learn to ask good questions instead.

Comment: @xenoid Okay sure.